# Is there anyway to format code like this, in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-formatting

befor:
[image]

after:
[image]

I tried Code Alignment, not smart, please help, thanks.

Comment: I don't know any. You can achieve it manually by `Tab`s

Comment: you need to manage it own your own. Visual Studio formats the code by default as given in _before_ image.

Comment: I can suggest you to create an extension or macro for Visual Studio or for Resharper ;).